# Show that $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}(1-e^{-t^2})dt$ is an odd function

Tags: calculus

Here's the problem that I want to try and solve:

> Show that $f(x)=\int_{0}^{x}(1-e^{-t^2})dt$ is an odd function

I hope you can give me feedback on whether this solution is proper or not.

**Solution:**

In order to prove that it's odd, one have to show that $f(-x)=-f(x)$. Thus, we have:

$f(-x)=\int_{0}^{-x}(1-e^{-t^2})dt$

Doing a substitution, we let $u = -t$, and so $du = -dt$:

$f(-x)=\int_{0}^{x}(1-e^{-u^2})(-1)du=-\int_{0}^{x}(1-e^{-u^2})du=-f(x)$

Which was to be proved.

---

I'm mainly concerned whether my substitution should change the sign of the upper bound. So I'd really appreciate if you could explain whether that move is correct / incorrect.

Thank you!

Comment: Another approach: by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, $f$ is differentiable and its derivative is the integrand. The integrand is clearly even, hence $f$ is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is correct. If $t$ takes any value from $0$ to $-x$, $-t(=u)$ takes any value from $0(=-0)$ to $x(=-(-x))$.